# `yield` throughout parsing in flask

Tags: python, flask-restful, yield-keyword, yield-from

First, I use flask.

Second, I `yield` values like the code below.

```
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        def generate():
            yield '<pre>'
            yield "Processing...\n"
            file = CheckFile(f.filename, f.read())
            file.parse()
            for note in file.validate():
                if note.oddity_type == Note.ERROR:
                    yield '<span style="color: red;">%s</span>' % str(note)
                if note.type == Note.WARNING:
                    yield '<span style="color: orange;">%s</span>' % str(note)
                if note.type == Note.INFO:
                    yield '<span style="color: blue;">%s</span>' % str(note)
                if note.type == Note.FATAL:
                    yield '<span style="color: red;">%s</span>' % str(note)
            yield '</pre>'
        return Response(stream_with_context(generate()))
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return app.send_static_file('index.html')
```

So after the `__init__ in`CheckFile`is completed, I`return`values with`yield` to the response.

What I want to do is to be able to `yield` values in `__init__` and in `file.parse()`.

Comment: I read it three times but it does not get clearer what you are trying to do.

Comment: Alright, I've clarified it a bit. Is it better @KlausD. ?

Comment: Make `parse` a generator and use the `yield from` keyword. I don't think it would be a good idea to do the same with the constructor. It's not its purpose and I have no idea if that would even work.

Comment: Yeah, that's actually my idea as well, however, I'm not really sure how implement that (that "the parse is a generator"). Basically the parsing is just reading a JSON file and reading certain keys of that JSON.

Comment: You just need to have one or more `yield` statements in `parse`, then `yield from file.parse()`. I did not test it, so give me a notice if it works.

Comment: But then I need to do ALL parsing in `parse` right? I can't call any functions or anything...?

Comment: Why not? You can deliver to other generators with `yield from`. That also works on generator expressions as an easy way to wrap other iterators like lists returned by functions.